# What's the newest/most powerful processor a AM3+ 880 motherboard supports?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, am3

It's an Asrock 880GMH/USB3, I been thinking about getting a more powerful processor, preferably a hexacore since I do a lot of multitasking and I could use the extra 2 cores.

Could I get a piledriver CPU on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally what controls the CPU a board can take is the 1) socket and 2) chipset.  So look at processors compatible with the board's socket and chipset.  The [service manual](http://download.asrock.com/manual/880GMHUSB3.pdf) for the motherboard, usually easily available with a quick search, usually also tells you (on page 6 in this case).

> - Support for Socket AM3 processors: AMD PhenomTM II X4 /  X3 / X2 (except 920 / 940) / Athlon II X4 / X3 / X2 / Sempron  processors

On that page of the manual:

> - Six-Core CPU Ready

Also, ASRock appears to have a list [here](http://www.asrock.com/mb/cpu.asp?Model=880GMH/USB3%20R2.0).

---

Also, read [the answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/651924/cpu-and-motherboard-compatibility).  The BIOS and motherboard also must support the CPU you want to put on the board.