# CPU and motherboard compatibility

Tags: cpu, compatibility, sockets, cpu-z

I used CPU-Z to identify my socket and it said 479 mPGA. Also got chipset information and used intel site to check out compatible processors. Turns out a lot of processors were compatible with the chipset. Some a lot faster, but that doesn't mean the socket compatible does it?

I ordered a processor off the list anyway (was very cheap), but now I'm not sure if it's compatible with my socket. So I looked at my current processor and the compatible sockets and  479 mPGA wasn't there. Has CPU-Z messed up? The processor I ordered is intel core duo T8100 by the way.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure the CPU is compatible with your motherboard. You need your motherboard make and model and possibly the BIOS version. With that, you can check CPU compatibility (usually on the manufacturer's web site). If you need to upgrade the BIOS, do so before you remove the existing CPU.

Compatibility with the socket and the chipset is not enough. If the motherboard BIOS doesn't know how to setup the CPU, it won't work. If the motherboard's VRM can't supply the CPU the voltage or power it needs, it won't work. And so on.